# Hibernate: Forign key needs to be primary key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two entities: a User and a Guest who contains (references) user.
User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long user_id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String surname;
    ....
}
```

Guest:

```
@Entity
public class Guest {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id_fk")
    private User user;

    private int visits;
    ...    
}
```

As you can guess, I want my foreign key user_id (user_id_fk) to be primary key of my guest, but this code doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` may work (I'm not sure)

Your guest class :

```
@Entity
public class Guest {
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    private int visits;
    ...    
}
```

But you should look for implementing [inheritance](http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/implementing-inheritance-in-hibernate.html)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by implementing inheritance as you suggested. I was looking for a solution in a wrong place without even thinking about inheritance.

Comment: Thank you so much, you just saved me a few hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

Mention column name in the @JoinColumn not the foreign key constraint name.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Y. Tarion, I was able to solve my problem.

For anyone who might find this helpful, I'm posting my code here:

User:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long user_id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String surname;
    //...constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

Guest:

```
@Entity
public class Guest extends User {

    private int visits;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Guest> friends;

    public int getVisits() {
        return visits;
    }

    public void setVisits(int visits) {
        this.visits = visits;
    }

    public List<Guest> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<Guest> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }
}
```